# C++ Matrix Operator+

Tags: c++, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation, addition

The method `template <class T> const Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T> &rhs) const` for program `matrix.cc` should be able to return the sum of calling object's matrix and rhs's matrix as a new object. Also, the lhs and rhs rows and cols will be equal.

The error output that I am receiving from the compiler is:

```
[hw7] make clean && make bin/test_add && ./bin/test_add                                           UserSettings  ✱
rm -f bin/*
g++   -std=c++11   -Wall       -I inc   -I src   -c   src/test_matrix_add.cc -o bin/test_matrix_add.o
g++   -std=c++11   -Wall       -I inc   -I src   -o   bin/test_add bin/test_matrix_add.o
Testing Matrix::operator+
  Expected Matrix2[0][0]: 3.0, Actual: 1
  FAILED
```

Could someone let me know why I receive this "Failed" output when I know I pass the `// TEST MUL ASSIGMENT OP CORRECT RETURN` section.

Here is my matrix.cc:

```
#include <matrix.h>

template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix() {
  rows_ = 0;
  cols_ = 0;
  m_ = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols)
    : rows_(rows), cols_(cols) {
  m_ = new T *[rows_];
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
    m_[i] = new T[cols_];
  }
}

template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T> &that) {
  rows_ = that.rows_;
  cols_ = that.cols_;
  m_ = new T *[rows_];
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
    m_[i] = new T[cols_];
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols_; ++j) {
      m_[i][j] = that.m_[i][j];
    }
  }
}

template <class T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
    delete[] m_[i];  // delete columns
  }
  delete[] m_;  // delete columns
}

template <class T>
T Matrix<T>::Get(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const {
  if (row > rows_ && col > cols_) {
    throw std::out_of_range("error: index out of range");
  }
  return this->m_[row][col];
}

template <class T>
const Matrix<T> &Matrix<T>::operator=(const Matrix<T> &rhs) {
  if (this == &rhs) {
    return *this;
  }  // returns the address

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
    delete[] m_[i];
  }
  delete[] m_;

  rows_ = rhs.rows_;
  cols_ = rhs.cols_;
  m_ = new T *[rows_];
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
    m_[i] = new T[cols_];
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols_; ++j) {
      m_[i][j] = rhs.m_[i][j];
    }
  }
  return *this;
}

template <class T>
const Matrix<T> &Matrix<T>::operator*=(T rhs) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols_; ++j) {
      m_[i][j] *= rhs;
    }
  }
  return *this;
}

template <class T>
const Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T> &rhs) const {
  if (!(this->cols_ == rhs.cols_) || (this->rows_ == rhs.rows_)) {
    std::cout << "Cannont add matrices. Wrong dimensions\n";
    exit(0);
  }
  Matrix<T> lhs;
  lhs.rows_ = this->rows_;
  lhs.cols_ = this->cols_;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lhs.rows_; ++i) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < lhs.cols_; ++j) {
      lhs[i][j] += rhs[i][j];
    }
  }
  return lhs;
}
```

Here is my matrix.h:

```
#include <cassert>
// using assert
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Matrix {
 public:
  friend class MatrixTester;

  Matrix();  // for testing, useless in practice
  Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols);
  Matrix(const Matrix<T> &that);
  ~Matrix();
  T Get(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const;
  const Matrix<T> &operator=(const Matrix<T> &rhs);
  const Matrix<T> &operator*=(T rhs);
  const Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> &rhs) const;

 private:
  T **m_;
  unsigned int rows_;
  unsigned int cols_;
};

#include <matrix.cc>  //NOLINT
```

This is my test_matrix_add.cc tester:

```
#include <test_matrix.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  MatrixTester tester;

  cout << "Testing Matrix::operator+" << endl;
  if (tester.Test_AddOp()) {
    cout << "  PASSED" << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  cout << "  FAILED" << endl;
  return 1;
}

bool MatrixTester::Test_AddOp() const {
  const int kRows = 4, kCols = 5;
  Matrix<double> m1;
  m1.m_ = new double*[kRows];
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < kRows; ++i) {
    m1.m_[i] = new double[kCols];

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < kCols; ++j)
      m1.m_[i][j] = (i + 1.0) * (j + 1.0);
  }
  m1.rows_ = kRows;
  m1.cols_ = kCols;

  // TEST ADDITION CORRECTNESS
  Matrix<double> m2;
  m2 = m1;
  // + m1 + m1;
  if (m2.m_[0][0] != 3) {
    cout << "  Expected Matrix2[0][0]: 3.0, Actual: " << m2.m_[0][0] << endl;
    return false;
  }
  if (m2.m_[1][3] != 24.0) {
    cout << "  Expected Matrix2[1][3]: 24.0, Actual: " << m2.m_[1][3] << endl;
    return false;
  }
  if (m2.m_[2][2] != 27.0) {
    cout << "  Expected Matrix2[2][2]: 27.0, Actual: " << m2.m_[2][2] << endl;
    return false;
  }
  if (m2.m_[3][4] != 60.0) {
    cout << "  Expected Matrix2[2][2]: 60.0, Actual: " << m2.m_[2][2] << endl;
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: `lhs` is not the left-handside of the addition. It is supposed to be the *result* of the addition, i.e. the object that is returned (see your `return` statement). I suggest you rename it. The left-hand side of the addition is `this`. Now consider which values you need to add up and where you need to store the result. Currently you are adding `lhs` (the result) and `rhs` (the right-hand side) and you store the result in `lhs` (the result) here: `lhs[i][j] += rhs[i][j];`. Does that seem correct to you?

Comment: What *may* make sense is that you think of `lhs` as a *copy* of the left-hand side operator. But this would require you to actually construct it as a copy of `*this`.

Comment: The posted `matrix.h` includes `matrix.cc`, which includes `matrix.h`. Do you have include guards in your real code?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes I do have include guards.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there is way too much code here.

To address your problem, I see don't see you allocating memory to `lhs.m_`. This is a problem because you initialize `lhs` with the default constructor, which only assigns `this->m_` to a `nullptr`.

To fix this, this should work (although untested):

```cpp
template <class T>
const Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T>& rhs) const
{
    if (!(this->cols_ == rhs.cols_) || (this->rows_ == rhs.rows_))
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot add matrices. Wrong dimensions\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    Matrix<T> lhs;
    lhs.rows_ = this->rows_;
    lhs.cols_ = this->cols_;

    // Allocate memory for `lhs.m_`, like you did in your 2nd constructor
    lhs.m_ = new T* [rows_];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rows_; ++i)
    {
        m_[i] = new T[cols_];
    }
    // [End] allocation

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lhs.rows_; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < lhs.cols_; ++j)
        {
            lhs[i][j] += rhs[i][j];
        }
    }
    return lhs;
}
```

Also, somewhat unrelated, be careful that you consistently treat `m_` as a double-pointer. I didn't read all your code, but just be cautious. And also remember that you have to deallocate *all* the memory you allocated with `new` in your destructor. Personally, I believe you should use smart pointers from `<memory>` (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`, etc), which you can learn more about [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smart-pointers-cpp/). Using smart pointers would make the pointers deallocate the memory on their own and you wouldn't have to worry about memory leaks.

**Edit 1**
As walnut stated, a better solution would be to just call the 2nd constructor, which will allocate the memory for you. So, your revised function would be:

```cpp
template <class T>
/**
 Note:
   > When you call this function (e.g. Matrix<T> new_mat = mat1 + mat2),
     `mat1` is `this` and `mat2` is what you're calling `rhs`. I've done
     some renaming and corrected your logic errors here
*/
const Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T>& other) const
{
    if (!(this->cols_ == other.cols_) || (this->rows_ == other.rows_))
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot add matrices. Wrong dimensions\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    // Call the 2nd constructor
    Matrix<T> res(this->rows_, this->cols_);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < res.rows_; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < res.cols_; ++j)
        {
            res.m_[i][j] = this->m_[i][j] + other.m_[i][j];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Edit 2**
The above code has been correct to add the matrices correctly, as per @walnut's comment.

Comment: @walnut Oh yes, I was just trying to fix the most apparent error. I'll go back and revise again lol

Comment: My other question for this post is: Is the addition tester file right? Does it correctly call the addition operator for the two matrices?